# What does "dragon to mouse" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was reading *The Economist*, and I came across this paragraph (full article here: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XST-JdB3sT4J:https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/04/16/is-china-winning+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> A test of China’s ambitions will be how it acts in the race for a
>   vaccine. Should it get there first, success could be used as a
>   national triumph and a platform for global co-operation. Another test
>   is debt relief for poor countries. On April 15th the g20, including
>   China, agreed to let indebted nations suspend debt payments to its
>   members for eight months. In the past China has haggled over debt
>   behind closed doors and bilaterally, **dragon to mouse**, to extract
>   political concessions. If the g20’s decision means the government in
>   Beijing is now willing to co-ordinate with other creditors and be more
>   generous, that would be a sign it is ready to spend money to acquire a
>   new role.

What does the "dragon to mouse" refer to here?

Thanks!

Comment: The quotation seems contradictory. A **dragon to mouse** relationship is hardly "bilateral", more like "one sided".

Comment: Bilateral just contrasts with multi-lateral; neither implies relative strength of the parties, @WeatherVane

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is juxtaposing the awesome political, military, and economic might of China, against the comparatively meager stature of their rivals. Following the phrase "behind closed doors and bilaterally..." which means that it is a one-on-one "negotiation," with nobody else there to witness the scenario or to stand up for the less powerful entity. The "dragon to mouse" metaphor is highlighting this highly lop-sided power dynamic. Just picture a dragon negotiating with a mouse in a dark room and that pretty much says it all.

Comment: China is often symbolically represented as a dragon.

Comment: "Cat and mouse" or "fox and chicken" or "wolf and sheep" might be more common for an uneven power relationship, but in this case, dragon is strongly associated with China so a different comparison is used.